# Why aren't my Yongnuo 605N wireless triggers working with my YN568ex off-camera flash?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, off-camera-flash, wireless-triggers, yongnuo

I have a pair of Yongnuo rf605n wireless flash trigger transceivers and can not (despite several hours of trying) get them to fire my Yongnuo 568ex flash off camera. I have one mounted on the camera (Nikon D750) and one on the flash mounted off-camera. I have set everything to same group and channel. There seems to be some communication between the 605's but the flash will not fire when I snap the shutter. Even if I take the camera out of the picture and just try using the 605s and the flash by themselves it will not fire.  Also, the flash will fire in the optical line of sight mode using the camera's flash and the 605's work fine as shutter triggers.

What can I do about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of other things to check:

- Are both of the YN-605Ns in the same 603/602 mode?
- Is the YN-568EX ***out*** of all slave modes? [slave modes tell the flash to only listen to the sensor panel and to ignore the foot--the radio triggers are on the foot].
- Without the camera or flash, does using the test button on the transmitter 605N fire the receiver 605N? (check indicator lights).
- Is the group you're using set to fire on the transmitter?
- Are all batteries in good health and fully charged?
- Have you checked how the transmitter is seated on the camera hotshoe? (i.e., pushed all the way forward?)
- Have you checked that all contacts/pins are clean?

Comment: Solved--it was your second bullet point--I thought it need to be in one of the slave modes. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Gigi You're welcome! consider [accepting this as the answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).